# Display HTML entities on browser

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a code of HTML entity on browser, but they do not show up it convert into their respective element on browser window in chrome and all browsers but i want to display the code of html element without converting using php echo function its possible or not please resolve.

Comment: I'm not really getting, what you mean? You want to display the entity code? If so, use `&amp:nbsp;`.

Comment: Can you please provide your code?  (note in HTML you can use &nbsp; to create a non-breaking space)

Comment: echo '<pre>
here comes your preformatted and escaped &lt;html&gt;-code
</pre>';

Comment: i want display like &lt;html&gt; not a <html>

Comment: @P.K use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for that.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i use htmlentities but it print <html> i want &lt;

Comment: @P.K Show us the full code mate!

Comment: @P.K See with your own eyes: http://ideone.com/ErvvBc

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the `&` into `&amp;`. You can use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to do that:

```
echo htmlentities("<html>");    // &lt;html&gt;
```

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/ErvvBc)

If you wanna get `&lt;html&gt;`, then try doing it twice:

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("<html>"));
```

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Gc4cYq)

Comment: which browser do you use i get <html> in chrome and mozila

Comment: @P.K Wait... What do you wanna get then? If you wanna get `&lt;html&gt;`, then try doing it twice: [`echo htmlentities(htmlentities("<html>"));`](http://ideone.com/Gc4cYq)...

Comment: simple i want print html code for example echo htmlentities("<html>"); in these case i want &lt;html&gt; in output.

Comment: @P.K Updated answer. Check.

Comment: @P.K What's happening now? Did you get what you expected? Update me.

Comment: its working but not all entities i tried ("%html%") so it display %html% not their code.

Comment: @P.K ^ What did you expect then? What's the code for the above?